# Current across a silicon diode

Tags: semiconductors

[image]
Which method or theorem can I use to solve the current across a silicon diode considering the two DC voltage sources?

Comment: Voltage is across.  Current is through.  Which do you reall need?

Comment: Node analysis seems like it would be helpful here, you might be able to get something out of mesh analysis too.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, remove the diode.

Now you have two voltage sources, with two voltage dividers across them.

For each source+divider, calculate first the open circuit voltage (notice anything about the resistor values? you can do that in your head), and second the output impedance (OK, that will need a calculator). Looking up Thevenin's theorem could help here.

Now you have two effective voltages, and know their source impedance. Reconnect the diode.